# Difficulty in understanding a recursive decorated function

Tags: python

I have the below code where I am decorating a recursive function, but i am unable to understand some portions of the code.

```
def deco_func(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Decorating', args)
        res = f(*args)
        print(res)

    return wrapper


@deco_func
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact(n - 1)

fact(4)
```

**Note :**

***1. f inside the wrapper function actually points to original version of fact function since it comes from enclosing scope and its value is closed by wrapper.***

***2. Recursive calls inside the fact function calls the decorated version of fact which is wrapper.***

So as per my understanding the stack trace would look like this.

```
res = f(4)
    = 4 * wrapper(3) = 4 * f(3)
    = 4 * 3 * wrapper(2) = 4 * 3 * f(2)
    = 4 * 3 * 2 * wrapper(1) = 4 * 3 * 2 * f(1)
    = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * wrapper(0) = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * f(0)
```

At this point n will be 0 and hence f(0) will return 1 so that stack would look like below

`res    = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1`

So `res` should be 24, but its value is 1 which i am not able to understand. Also at this point i get an exception

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'`

But as soon as I add a return statement at the bottom of the wrapper function like `return res`, everything works fine.

I do not understand why not having a return is creating a problem here, because inside the wrapper function control never goes beyond `res = f(*args)` till recursion is complete. So a final call like `f(0)` would result in `res = 5*4*3*2*1` and as above illustrated res should be evaluated to 24 and then  the control should go to next statement. So why NOT having the return statement in wrapper is creating problem when the return would only execute once `res` has been calculated

I know i am missing something major here but i am not able to figure it out conceptually what goes wrong if we remove the return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original function `f` returns a numeric value.

Your decorated function does not, which means that it returns `None`. This is why a recursive call tries to multiply `n` by `None`, hence the error.

The missing piece is `return res`.

Comment: I know this is the missing piece here but i was an explanation of the stack frame on how exactly is the return value is generated,

Comment: Can you please help me in understanding the same ?

Comment: Your `wrapper`, the result of decorator application, now replaces `f`. If `f` returned a value, the `wrapper` should return the value it received from the call to the original `f`. If `wrapper` does not return the value, it cannot be substituted for `f`. It does not take any recursion to show. Decorate a trivial function that returns argument + 1, and see the difference.

Comment: you mean fact right and not f ?? because f always will point to original undercoated version.

Comment: @Rohit: The decorated `fact` cannot be substituted for undecorated `fact` if the decoration wrapper does not return what the undecorated function (`f`) returns. This is the case when running the whole thing in a debugger, step by step, is very instructive and explanatory. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

A decorator *replaces* the function, so when you refer to `fact` inside the `fact` function, you're actually referring to the decorated function, which is `wrapper`. Therefore, `wrapper` is called once for each level of recursion, and when unwinding the return value is the value returned by `wrapper`, which is `None` when you do not have an explicit return statement.

To work correctly, `wrapper` must return the `res` value, so that the recursion unwinds correctly.

```
def deco_func(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Decorating', args)
        res = f(*args) # calls undecorated 'fact'
        print(res)
        return res # !!! so None is not returned implicitly

    return wrapper


@deco_func
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact(n - 1) # calls 'wrapper' (aka decorated 'fact')

fact(4)
```

Comment: i understand that but as i posted in my question that each call to wrapper would mean a new call like this f(n-1) which and this continues till f(0), at which point the fact(0) returns 1, so res = 4*3*2*1*1. So won't the return should come from fact(0) which is actually 1.

Comment: @Rohit No, `fact(0)` returns `None`, because, as I said, the decorator *replaces* the function. That's where the error comes from.

Comment: fact(0) would translate to wrapper(0), correct?, now going through wrapper(0) would make call like f(0) which would call undercoated version fact(0) and returns1 .. I think this is my sole confusion that how even decorated fact(0) would return none when we have the base case for n=0.

Comment: Can you explain a stack frame here, maybe that help me better.

Comment: Can you please reply and help me understanding this maybe with a stack frame explanation ?

Comment: can you please reply !!